# How to save parent id through javascript in nested sublists

Tags: php, jquery

**I have a nested list  with any number of li's and any number of ul's inside the li's where every li has 2 hidden inputs: an id and an id of the parent.**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" name="question[id][]" value="'. $sub['id'] .'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="question[parent][]" value="'. $question['id'] .'" />
        <ul>
            <li>
            <input type="hidden" name="question[id][]" value="'. $sub['id'] .'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="question[parent][]" value="'. $question['id'] .'" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" name="question[id][]" value="'. $sub['id'] .'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="question[parent][]" value="'. $question['id'] .'" />
        <ul>
            <li>
            <input type="hidden" name="question[id][]" value="'. $sub['id'] .'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="question[parent][]" value="'. $question['id'] .'" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <input type="hidden" name="question[id][]" value="'. $sub['id'] .'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="question[parent][]" value="'. $question['id'] .'" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I am using jQuery sortable to sort the nested list and now after sorting them I need to save the appropriate parent id to each item in the sublist.

Theoretically the parent id of each sub question is the value of the first input of the second closest ul. 
Also if there is no parent ul, then I want to set the parent id to 0.
How do I find it? This is what I have so far:

```
$('#reorder_form').submit(function(){
    $('li').each(function() {
        $id = $(this).closest('ul').closest('li').find("input[name='question[id]']").val();
        if(typeof($id) == 'undefined') $id=0;
        $(this).find("input[name='question[parent]']").val($id);
    });
});
```

I am not 100% sure that this is how you properly loop through each input because I am hitting each twice. Perhaps I should loop through the li's instead?

Answer (score 0):

You want to go up to the closest li, then up again to the closest li before that then back to the input. To be really semantic:

```
$id = $(this).closest('li').closest('li').find('input[name^="question[id]"]').first().val();
```

Not checked. I would do it in jsfiddle but it appears to be broken.

```
$('li input[name^="question[parent]"]').each(function() {
  var $id = $(this).closest('li').closest('li').find('input[name^="question[id]"]').val();
  if(typeof($id)=="undefined") $id=0; 
  $(this).val($id);
});
```

Just one note if `.save` points to a button in a form bear in mind there is (usually) more than one way to submit a form. `$('#theform').on('submit', function(){...});` is the best method.

Also

```
if(typeof($id) == undefined)
```

I'm pretty sure that would always return false because typeof won't == undefined, it will be a value, which may be 'undefined'.

```
if(typeof($id) == "undefined")
```

Comment: Well it would have to be the closest ul but I see what you are saying.

Comment: `li` is fine to get you there from the html you've supplied

Comment: but there could be any number of li's in each ul. Do you not need to use .parents() to go up?

Comment: It would be useful if you edited your question to show that. No, `closest()` goes up too.

Comment: That is the first thing that I said

Comment: I will highlight it because it is not very obvious.

Comment: Actually from what you wrote li is correct. UL would mean you get the first input in the first list element each time

Comment: Ok just one more question. Because now, I am looping through the li's how to do I save the value of the input. $(this).find(" input[name^='question[parent]']").val($id); ???

Comment: see if the change works. what you're after is `.siblings()` or you could have gone up a level then found that element. I can't check my code, jsfiddle is not working.

Comment: actually you don't need `siblings` if you just start from that element in the first place.

Comment: if I use .closet('li'), this finds the li that I am currently in, then another .closet('li') finds the li that comes before that. What I am trying to do is find the ul, not the one that I am in, but the one that  it is contained in so if there is <ul id="one"><ul id="two"></ul></ul> and I am in two, I want to find one and if I am in one, I want 'undefined'. Does that makes sense?

Comment: I'm not following.  If you traverse up to the UL from a 2nd level input you get to the ul that contains one li and those two inputs. If you then go up again you get to top level ul which contains all the inputs so the first you find() is the very first. If you add unique IDs to your HTML and give written examples of what IDs two separate  input fields pick up it would make better sense.

Comment: thank you for your help, I would never have gotten it without you.    You got me thinking the way that I needed to.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to save the id and parent id of any number of li's containing any number of ul's containing any number of li's with the cooresponding html from the question. I admit it is slightly hackish, but it is what I came up with. Hope it helps someone.

```
        $('#reorder_form').submit(function(){
            $('li input[name^="question[parent]"]').each(function() {
                $ul = $(this).closest('ul').parent().closest('ul');
                $attr = $ul.attr("class");
                if(typeof($attr) == 'undefined')
                    $id=0;
                else
                    $id = $ul.find("li input[name^='question[id]']").val();
                $(this).val($id);

            });
        });
```